# Docker remote registries (beside docker.io)

Tags: docker

We are running an offline Kubernetes with Docker as the container engine.

We also have an artifact server which serves several container registries as remote (like docker.io or quay.io).

I managed to configure Docker to target docker.io.mylocalartifacts.com (fake URL of our server) and I can pull `hello-world:latest` or `docker.io/hello-world:latest` (or any docker.io images) and they get pulled from our remote (which is a mirror/cache).

But I can't find a way to tell Docker to target quay.io.mylocalartifacts.com for quay.io images.

For cri-o or podman, you can configure it in `/etc/containers/registries.conf` but Docker doesn't use that file.

Is there a way to configure Docker so that it pulls images from a specific repo?

Yes, I can move from Docker to cri-o or containerd but that's not the point of the question.

thank you

Comment: I migrated my cluster to containerd instead of Docker, and containerd can be configured to have alternate hostnames for any registry.
It would still be interesting to know if it's possible with Docker